# Efficient way to concatenate and sort seasonal time series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have a number of numpy arrays, each represents a series of seasonal data. The frequency is year.

- The 1st array has all the sales value in the 1st week of year,
  from year 2014 to year 2018.
- The 2nd array has all the sales value in the 2nd week of year,
  from year 2014 to year 2018.
- ...
- The 52nd array has all the sales value in the 52nd week of year,
  from year 2014 to year 2018.

The following example is kind of tricky as they are not strictly obtained by counting "week of year" and slicking. Rather, they are selected based on the remainder to 52 of a week's relative index to the beginning of time. But the idea is similar...

They look like this.

```
arr1 = array([[Timestamp('2014-01-04 00:00:00'), 138.52],
   [Timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00'), 25476.179999999997],
   [Timestamp('2016-01-02 00:00:00'), 87318.65000000001],
   [Timestamp('2016-12-31 00:00:00'), 194409.42],
   [Timestamp('2017-12-30 00:00:00'), 299190.06000000023]], dtype=object)

arr2 = array([[Timestamp('2014-01-11 00:00:00'), 0.0],
   [Timestamp('2015-01-10 00:00:00'), 23848.57000000001],
   [Timestamp('2016-01-09 00:00:00'), 86814.12],
   [Timestamp('2017-01-07 00:00:00'), 202016.92],
   [Timestamp('2018-01-06 00:00:00'), 344430.36000000004]], dtype=object)
```

Now I want to join them into a complete and sorted time series.

- So the indices will be `[arr1.index[0], arr2.index[0], arr3.index[0], ... arr52.index[0], (here we begin a new year) arr1.index[1], arr2.index[1], ...]`.
- The values will be `[arr1.value[0], arr2.value[0], arr3.value[0], ... arr52.value[0], (here we begin a new year) arr1.value[1], arr2.value[1], ...]`.

One way I can think of is to first concatenate all the subseries into a full series, and then sort the series by index.

But are there better ways to do this?

Thanks!

**Background**
The problem came up when I was trying to implement the [stl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_time_series) decomposition in Python and one step is to smooth every seasonal subseries independently, and then combine them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea.. Suppose we have all the subseries ready and neat.

1. First vertically stack all subseries.
2. Then loop through every column and concatenate them one after another.

So we avoid the sorting because of the structure of the subseries.

Example:

```
>> s1 
array([Timestamp('2013-12-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-27 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2015-12-26 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-12-24 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2017-12-23 00:00:00')], dtype=object)

>> s2
array([Timestamp('2014-01-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2016-01-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-12-31 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2017-12-30 00:00:00')], dtype=object)

>> np.vstack([s1, s2]).T.reshape([1, -1], order = 'c')[0]
array([Timestamp('2013-12-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-01-04 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2014-12-27 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2015-12-26 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-01-02 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2016-12-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-12-31 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2017-12-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-12-30 00:00:00')], dtype=object)
```